# How to merge two result columns into column with alternating results in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

For a table with columns A and B, select * from table will give back

A        B
A1      B1
A2      B2
A3      B3

Is there a way to query on this so that the result set is like this -

Merged
A1
B1
A2
B2
A3
B3

Appreciate any suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A union with some added spice to determine ordering would work:

```
SELECT col
FROM (
  SELECT 'A' as colname, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY A) as colrow, A as col FROM table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' as colname, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY B) as colrow, B as col FROM table
) sub
ORDER BY colrow, colname
```

Comment: Perfect! Not allowed to mark accepted for another 8 minutes but yes, order only matters within the tuple. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would write this as:

```
select merged
from ((select a as merged, a as ordcol, 1 as which from t
      ) union all
      (select b, a, 2 from t
      )
     ) t
order by ordcol, which;
```

Window functions aren't needed for this.

Answer (score 1):

Simple left join and case when will do it:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN T1.A = LEAD(T1.A) OVER (ORDER BY T1.A)  THEN T1.A
            ELSE T1.B
       END Merged
FROM MYTABLE T1
LEFT JOIN MYTABLE T2 ON T1.A <> T2.A;
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=10cbc9d8a5d387d73bcfb293c9aa31fb)

**Result**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a, rownum*2 as r FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT b, (rownum*2)+1 FROM table
ORDER BY r
```

You might have to turn them into subqueries and order by a/b - it wasn't really clear if your example data was sorted or if you're happy to just have the natural ordering so long as they're interleaved

Comment: You are missing one from clause. Also, how to remove r from resultset ? And how to order it to be | A1 | B1 |... ? Thank you for your answer. Cheers!

Comment: Remove R by wrapping the whole thing in another select and not selecting it. It's typically not too important to do so, b cause you can keep the query looking uncluttered and simply not use the R column in (for example) the front end

Comment: I didn't put a sort on for A1 B1 because it wasnt necessarily the case that that was real data (it looks like bogus data). If it is real data and it must sort that way, then sorting the queries before they are unioned will be acceptable (rownum will be generated in that order then)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was just pointing towards the desired op's output but the comment is useful I believe.